# Jquery If Not -

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here -

I want the following script to react only if the div with id #main-nav doesnt also have the class .scrolled

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(window).scrollTop()< ($(window).height()-50)){
        if (!("#main-nav".hasClass('submenu'))){ 
        $('#main-nav').removeClass('scrolled');
        alert ("REMOVED")
        }
    }
    else{
        if (!"#main-nav".hasClass('submenu')){ 
        $('#main-nav').addClass('scrolled'); 
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: `!("#main-nav"` should be `!$("#main-nav"`  (missing `$`)

Comment: and a few lines down: 'if (!"#main-nav".hasClass' should be 'if (!$("#main-nav").hasClass'

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn you gave me the correct answer first to be fair - so if you want the tick add as an answer

Comment: Ok mate. Answer added

Comment: cheers for your help - having one of those rushed days when bugs drive you nuts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few syntax errors...

```
   $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(window).scrollTop()< ($(window).height()-50)){
            if (!("#main-nav".hasClass('submenu'))){ // missing "$". Missing ")". Extra ")" near end
            $('#main-nav').removeClass('scrolled');
            alert ("REMOVED")
            }
        }
        else{
            if (!"#main-nav".hasClass('submenu')){ // Missing "$(". Missing ")"
            $('#main-nav').addClass('scrolled'); 
            }
        }
    });
```

Try this:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/n8ds4aLo/1/)

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(window).scrollTop()< ($(window).height()-50)){
        if (!$("#main-nav").hasClass('submenu')){
        $('#main-nav').removeClass('scrolled');
        alert ("REMOVED");
        }
    }
    else{
        if (!$("#main-nav").hasClass('submenu')){
        $('#main-nav').addClass('scrolled'); 
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Missed an extra `)`. Corrected

Answer (score 1):

Put the $() selector like this

```
if (!$("#main-nav").hasClass('submenu')){
```

Answer (score 1):

`"#main-nav"` is a string and strings in JS do not have a function like `hasClass`.

You have to pass that selector/string into the jQuery (or find) function to get a jQuery object. Afterwards you may check with `hasClass`:

```
if( !jQuery("#main-nav").hasClass( 'submenu' ) )
```

On the other hand, you could as well only select that element with a single selector:

```
if( jQuery("#main-nav.submenu").length > 0 )
```

Also, if you are re-using the same element multiple times, you should store it in a variable, because each call to `jQuery/$` will trigger a scan over the DOM which is a very costly operation.

```
var mainNav = jQuery( '#main-nav' );

if( !mainNav.hasClass( 'submenu' ) )
```